# Using Transient with Mapping to get Reference_Id of parent modal

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

Actually, I want to get Forienkey of parent modal in spring JPA Mapping. for that I perform patching of Transient variable to get trainer_id of the parent table in JSON Response.

```
@Transient
private Long trinerId;

@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch =  FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "trainer_id")
@JsonIgnore
private TrainerLoginDetails trainerLoginDetails;




public Long getTrinerId() {
    return trainerLoginDetails.getId();
}
```

Is this a good way to get Reference_Id of parent modal from its child?